# Reload site when session cookie expires in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I have a system that has a menu that shows certain links, as seen on the image below:

[image]

That menu has links that load in the center part of the dashboard using an iframe, like this:

[image]

I am working with sessions and I have a stipulated time so that once the session cookie expires I will not let any part of the website show them a route where I am configuring the middleware with the session control:

```
Route :: resource ('users', 'UserController') -> middleware ('auth');
```

My mistake is that when the cookie expires, the page reloads within the iframe, as seen here:

[image]

What do I want to achieve? I would like to ensure that if I click on one of these links, the login will not load within the iframe, but rather that the entire site will be reloaded and take me to the main page or, failing that (which would be the best) than if the session I expire, the site will refresh itself and take me to the main login page.

I tried to do something with jQuery using the event to capture the movement of the mouse and when it does not move in conjunction with creating a new cookie to be able to manipulate it, since I wanted to determine if the session cookie existed to refresh the page but how these cookies are encrypted I can't manipulate them but it didn't work out very well. I hope you can give me some other idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the every link (route) on which you are clicking you have to use middleware, and  check the session is expired or not, if it is expired then you can logout the user and redirect it to login page!

Comment: Hi, yes i use a middleware but this  redirect fine to login page but this is load in the iframe

Comment: okay, so you have to create a separate page for login after session is expired you can redirect the user on it.